# HTTP calls (with HttpWebRequest, RestSharp or HttpClient) extremely slow in LAN but not in WLAN

Tags: .net, http

I lately got a new notebook. Everything's working fine, except simple HTTP calls made from my application take 20-40 seconds each. But only when I'm connected via LAN, with WLAN the calls are fast as ever. Also my old notebook doesn't show this behavior. Disabling my antivirus SW and firewall had no effect.

I want to point out, everything else is working fine. My internet is working and I can browse without problem. Also other applications on my machine don't show this behavior. I only have this problem in my .NET core application (tested in core API, console and unit test project).

Also I've tried serval different clients `RestSharp`, `HttpClient` or a simple `HttpWebRequest` like here:

```
string url = "https://www.google.de";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Proxy = null;
using var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
await using var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string result = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
```

Some suggested to set `request.Proxy` to `null`. That didn't change anything however.

BTW: My `node` application works fine as well. No delays here.

There must be some strange network configuration on my machine messing with HTTP calls from .net applications. I just cannot figure out what it is. Any suggestions?